# select one div and unselected another one

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Working on the `div's`. I am doing changes that if one div is selected, it should deselect the another div.

The `div's` defined are in `ul li`

Like in every `li`, there is a div with same `classname` called as `inonset`. Now the div which is already selected is having a class of `inonset isactive`.

I am adding a `onclick` function on every `<div class="inonset" onclick="selectme(divid)">` to select it and unselect other, but how the other will be unelected, I am lost

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38nv5rft/)

Not have not added the javascript code yet, but from the code, it will clear what I am trying to do.

You will see initially one selected and others are there, i just trying to selected any other one and deselect the previous one, Hope my questions makes sense

Worst thing: I cannot use `Jquery`, Only `Dojo` or Plain `Javascript`

**Update #1**

```
<div class="optionsBox" align="left" id="Invoicing" onclick="chooseDiv(this);">
function chooseDiv(oObj){
    var d = document.getElementsByClassName("ul li div");
    alert(d.className);
```

It is giving me undefined and not looping over the classes

the `div` is having classes like

iv class="headerSelected isactive">

where `isactive` needs to be removed from the previous selected `div` and add to the newly selected `Div`

Comment: if you see the jsfiddle, the selected div is having a class of `isactive`

Comment: I tried like this: Update #1 in main Question

Answer (score 0):

First u need to change on click event for this:

```
onclick="selectme(this)"
```

And then in function:

```
function selectme(oObj){
  var d = document.getElementById("ul li div");
  d.removeAttribute("class");
  oObj.className = oObj.className + " otherclass";
}
```

It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the answer is still required or not. However, posting my approach of doing it.

```
function removeClass(className) {
    // convert the result to an Array object
    var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName(className)
    );
    for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
        var el = els[i];
        el.className = el.className.replace(
            new RegExp('(^|\\s+)' + className + '(\\s+|$)', 'g'),
            '$1'
        );
    }
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("inoneset");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        elements[i].onclick = function() {
            removeClass("isactive");
            //this.setAttribute("class", this.getAttribute("class") + " isactive");
            var headerElem = this.getElementsByClassName("headerSelected")[0];
            headerElem.setAttribute("class", headerElem.getAttribute("class") + " isactive");
            var addressElem = this.getElementsByClassName("selDelAddress")[0];
            addressElem.setAttribute("class", addressElem.getAttribute("class") + " isactive");
            var footerElem = this.getElementsByClassName("footerSelected")[0];
            footerElem.setAttribute("class", footerElem.getAttribute("class") + " isactive");
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/38nv5rft/18/

**Reasoning**

As you can see, there is a remove class function, that removes the class from the elements in the document. One can update it as per the requirement.

Then the main logic, which gets all the elements, iterate on them and bind the click function.

In click function, we are removing the inActive class from every element and then for current block, adding inActive class. Please note, as per the fiddle, I did not find the class on inoneset elements being updated, hence, commented out the code.

**Important Point**

Click event bubbles, hence, click on elements with showDelete and showDialog click functions will bubble the event to click event of inoneset i.e. click handler of inoneset will also be triggered. In order to stop the propagation of event to it, use event.stopPropogation() in showDelete and showDialog functions.